# How to use the Lemma inside a module in Coq?

Tags: coq

I defined a module type in one file called `A.v`

```
Module Type WeakPair.
...

End WeakPair.

Module WeakPairProps (Import WP : WeakPair).

 Lemma Weak_A ....

End WeakPairProps.
```

Then I want to define another file `B.v` that can use the `Lemma` in `WeakPairProps` for example : `Weak_A`.
Because `WeakPairProps` is not a module type so I do not know how to write a module that can reuse the lemma in `WeakPairProps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define a module that *implements* the module type `WeakPair` :

```
Module WeakPairImpl <: WeakPair.
(* stuff goes here *)
End WeakPairImpl.
```

Now you can *instantiate* the functor `WeakPairProps`:

```
Module WeakPairPropsInst := WeakPairProps(WeakPairImpl).
```

You are now able to refer to the lemma:

```
WeakPairPropsInst.lemma
```

You can *import* WeakPairPropsInst if you desire not to use qualified names.